# how to convert basic html theme to angular easily?

Tags: angularjs, html

I have been looking for some good ways to build up a **angular website** with help of basic html templates but it doesn't work with **carousel** and some other elements.

**Can any suggestion for slider in angular?**

Comment: Can you add code examples on what you have already tried and did not work? Something like jsfiddle would be better

Comment: sure let me add some codes here

Comment: [http://www.bootply.com/89193]
Currently i'm making use of this one and when repeating through ng-repeat its stacking on first slide itself so,if i add more than 4 it will show all the slides.

Answer (score 2):

Angular doesn't necessarily play nicely with jQuery plugins.
(I'm assuming you are using a jQuery carousel, you didn't say though).
That doesn't mean you can't use Jquery plugins, it just means you can't use them in a very Angular way.
Best to use Angular modules instead wherever possible.
See carousel at ...
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
This is a reliable library

Hope this helps

Angular slider here ... https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider ... but I've never tried it

Comment: I have already gone through this but i want the slides to be in this fashion [http://www.bootply.com/89193] can you help me out with this 3-4 slides in angular.